# ionic v3 directory structure explanation

Tags: ionic-framework, web, localhost, ionic3

I am trying to understanding ionic v3 directory structure since I'ved been working a lot on ionic v1.

Here is a project in ionic v3.
I am particularly curious what is .sourcemaps and www

so if I were to do any code modification, which sources should I touch ? previously in v1 I modify the code in www and then do ionic serve it will have all updates. in ionic v3, i think www directory is a build directory.

Please someone explain abit on the new directory structure and give guidance for simple code practice and debugging.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `Ionic v3` you will spend most of the time coding in the `src` folder. Most of everything you need to touch to create a wonderful app is generated in this folder.

`Platforms` folder is where you will see all the platform related folders get generated once you prepare your project for `android` or `iOS`ready.

`www` folder is were you place your medias your images and logo or any other necessary assets you wanted and use in your app.

For example if you want your app logo specific, you can place that logo inside the `www/assets` folder.

Comment: i thought the assets goes into src/assets ? www we dont need to commit right since its a temp/build folder. what about sourcemaps ? what is that for. i basically realize that i can change code in src while running ionic serve and it will update something. if i dont run ionic serve it will not update www directory i think. and those update are important for ios and android builds as well. is that how the code and build workflow works ?

Comment: I mean the platform specific assets goes into this folder. For example if you want a notification tone custom to your app goes into the www/assets folder. Or the logo that you wish to see as your app's logo goes into this folder. And as you mentioned, when you run `ionic serve` that is reflected in the www folder, meanwhile while you are building something with `ionic build android` that is taken effect in the platforms folder. I have close to no idea on sourcemaps, so sorry about that